# K8s SQL2019 HA Containers - Dude, where are my Pods?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, sql-server-2019

**New to K8s.  So far I have the following:**

- docker-ce-19.03.8
- docker-ce-cli-19.03.8
- containerd.io-1.2.13
- kubelet-1.18.5
- kubeadm-1.18.5
- kubectl-1.18.5
- etcd-3.4.10
- Use Flannel for Pod Overlay Net
- Performed all of the host-level work (SELinux permissive, swapoff, etc.)
- All Centos7 in an on-prem Vsphere envioronment (6.7U3)

**I've built all my configs and currently have:**

- a 3-node external/stand-alone etcd cluster with peer-to-peer and client-server encrypted transmissions
- a 3-node control plane cluster -- kubeadm init is bootstrapped with x509s and targets to the 3 etcds (so stacked etcd never happens)
- HAProxy and Keepalived are installed on two of the etcd cluster members, load-balancing access to the API server endpoints on the control plane (TCP6443)
- 6-worker nodes
- Storage configured with the in-tree Vmware Cloud Provider (I know it's deprecated)--and yes, this is my DEFAULT SC

**Status Checks:**

- kubectl cluster-info reports:

> ```
> [me@km-01 pods]$ kubectl cluster-info
> Kubernetes master is running at https://k8snlb:6443
> KubeDNS is running at https://k8snlb:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
> ```

kubectl get all --all-namespaces reports:

```
[me@km-01 pods]$ kubectl get all --all-namespaces -owide
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE                      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
ag1           pod/mssql-operator-68bcc684c4-rbzvn                   1/1     Running   0          86m   10.10.4.133   kw-02.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/coredns-66bff467f8-k6m94                          1/1     Running   4          20h   10.10.0.11    km-01.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/coredns-66bff467f8-v848r                          1/1     Running   4          20h   10.10.0.10    km-01.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-km-01.bogus.local            1/1     Running   8          10h   x.x.x..25   km-01.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-km-01.bogus.local   1/1     Running   2          10h   x.x.x..25   km-01.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-7l76c                       1/1     Running   0          10h   x.x.x..30   kw-01.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-8kft7                       1/1     Running   0          10h   x.x.x..33   kw-04.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-r5kqv                       1/1     Running   0          10h   x.x.x..34   kw-05.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-t6xcd                       1/1     Running   0          10h   x.x.x..35   kw-06.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-vhnx8                       1/1     Running   0          10h   x.x.x..32   kw-03.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-xdk2n                       1/1     Running   0          10h   x.x.x..31   kw-02.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-z4kfk                       1/1     Running   4          20h   x.x.x..25   km-01.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-49hsl                                  1/1     Running   0          10h   x.x.x..35   kw-06.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-62klh                                  1/1     Running   0          10h   x.x.x..34   kw-05.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-64d5t                                  1/1     Running   0          10h   x.x.x..30   kw-01.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-6ch42                                  1/1     Running   4          20h   x.x.x..25   km-01.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-9css4                                  1/1     Running   0          10h   x.x.x..32   kw-03.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-hgrx8                                  1/1     Running   0          10h   x.x.x..33   kw-04.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-ljlsh                                  1/1     Running   0          10h   x.x.x..31   kw-02.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-km-01.bogus.local            1/1     Running   5          20h   x.x.x..25   km-01.bogus.local   <none>           <none>

NAMESPACE     NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)                  AGE   SELECTOR
ag1           service/ag1-primary     NodePort    10.104.183.81    x.x.x..30,x.x.x..31,x.x.x..32,x.x.x..33,x.x.x..34,x.x.x..35   1433:30405/TCP           85m   role.ag.mssql.microsoft.com/ag1=primary,type=sqlservr
ag1           service/ag1-secondary   NodePort    10.102.52.31     x.x.x..30,x.x.x..31,x.x.x..32,x.x.x..33,x.x.x..34,x.x.x..35   1433:30713/TCP           85m   role.ag.mssql.microsoft.com/ag1=secondary,type=sqlservr
ag1           service/mssql1          NodePort    10.96.166.108    x.x.x..30,x.x.x..31,x.x.x..32,x.x.x..33,x.x.x..34,x.x.x..35   1433:32439/TCP           86m   name=mssql1,type=sqlservr
ag1           service/mssql2          NodePort    10.109.146.58    x.x.x..30,x.x.x..31,x.x.x..32,x.x.x..33,x.x.x..34,x.x.x..35   1433:30636/TCP           86m   name=mssql2,type=sqlservr
ag1           service/mssql3          NodePort    10.101.234.186   x.x.x..30,x.x.x..31,x.x.x..32,x.x.x..33,x.x.x..34,x.x.x..35   1433:30862/TCP           86m   name=mssql3,type=sqlservr
default       service/kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>                                                                    443/TCP                  23h   <none>
kube-system   service/kube-dns        ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>                                                                    53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   20h   k8s-app=kube-dns

NAMESPACE     NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE   CONTAINERS     IMAGES                                   SELECTOR
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-amd64     7         7         7       7            7           <none>                   20h   kube-flannel   quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.12.0-amd64     app=flannel
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm       0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   20h   kube-flannel   quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.12.0-arm       app=flannel
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm64     0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   20h   kube-flannel   quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.12.0-arm64     app=flannel
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le   0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   20h   kube-flannel   quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.12.0-ppc64le   app=flannel
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-s390x     0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   20h   kube-flannel   quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.12.0-s390x     app=flannel
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                7         7         7       7            7           kubernetes.io/os=linux   20h   kube-proxy     k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.18.7            k8s-app=kube-proxy

NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS       IMAGES                                          SELECTOR
ag1           deployment.apps/mssql-operator   1/1     1            1           86m   mssql-operator   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/ha:2019-CTP2.1-ubuntu   app=mssql-operator
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns          2/2     2            2           20h   coredns          k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7                        k8s-app=kube-dns

NAMESPACE     NAME                                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS       IMAGES                                          SELECTOR
ag1           replicaset.apps/mssql-operator-68bcc684c4   1         1         1       86m   mssql-operator   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/ha:2019-CTP2.1-ubuntu   app=mssql-operator,pod-template-hash=68bcc684c4
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-66bff467f8          2         2         2       20h   coredns          k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7                        k8s-app=kube-dns,pod-template-hash=66bff467f8
```

**To the problem:**  There are a number of articles talking about a SQL2019 HA build.  It appears that every single one however, is in the cloud whereas mine is on-prem in a Vsphere env.  They appear to be very simple:  Run 3 scripts in this order:  operator.yaml, sql.yaml, and ag-service.yaml.

**My YAML's are based on:**  https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/high%20availability/Kubernetes/sample-manifest-files

For the blogs that actually screenshot the environment afterward, there should be at least 7 pods (1 Operator, 3 SQL Init, 3 SQL).  If you look at my aforementioned all --all-namespaces output, I have everything (and in a running state) but no pods other than the running Operator...???

**I actually broke the control plane back to a single-node** just to try to isolate the logs.  /var/log/container/* and /var/log/pod/* contain nothing of value to indicate a problem with storage or any other reason the the Pods are non-existent.  It's probably also worth noting that I started using the latest sql2019 label:  2019-latest but when I got the same behavior there, I decided to try to use the old bits since so many blogs are based on CTP 2.1.

I can create PVs and PVCs using the VCP storage provider.  I have my Secrets and can see them in the Secrets store.

I'm at a loss as to explain why pods are missing or where to look after checking journalctl, the daemons themselves, and /var/log and I don't see any indication there's even an attempt to create them -- the kubectl apply -f mssql-server2019.yaml that I adapted runs to completion and without error indicating 3 sql objects and 3 sql services get created.  But here is the file anyway targeting CTP2.1:

```
cat << EOF > mssql-server2019.yaml
apiVersion: mssql.microsoft.com/v1
kind: SqlServer
metadata:
  labels: {name: mssql1, type: sqlservr}
  name: mssql1
  namespace: ag1
spec:
  acceptEula: true
  agentsContainerImage: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/ha:2019-CTP2.1
  availabilityGroups: [ag1]
  instanceRootVolumeClaimTemplate:
    accessModes: [ReadWriteOnce]
    resources:
      requests: {storage: 5Gi}
    storageClass: default
  saPassword:
    secretKeyRef: {key: sapassword, name: sql-secrets}
  sqlServerContainer: {image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CTP2.1'}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: {name: mssql1, namespace: ag1}
spec:
  ports:
  - {name: tds, port: 1433}
  selector: {name: mssql1, type: sqlservr}
  type: NodePort
  externalIPs:
    - x.x.x.30
    - x.x.x.31
    - x.x.x.32
    - x.x.x.33
    - x.x.x.34
    - x.x.x.35
---
apiVersion: mssql.microsoft.com/v1
kind: SqlServer
metadata:
  labels: {name: mssql2, type: sqlservr}
  name: mssql2
  namespace: ag1
spec:
  acceptEula: true
  agentsContainerImage: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/ha:2019-CTP2.1
  availabilityGroups: [ag1]
  instanceRootVolumeClaimTemplate:
    accessModes: [ReadWriteOnce]
    resources:
      requests: {storage: 5Gi}
    storageClass: default
  saPassword:
    secretKeyRef: {key: sapassword, name: sql-secrets}
  sqlServerContainer: {image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CTP2.1'}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: {name: mssql2, namespace: ag1}
spec:
  ports:
  - {name: tds, port: 1433}
  selector: {name: mssql2, type: sqlservr}
  type: NodePort
  externalIPs:
    - x.x.x.30
    - x.x.x.31
    - x.x.x.32
    - x.x.x.33
    - x.x.x.34
    - x.x.x.35
---
apiVersion: mssql.microsoft.com/v1
kind: SqlServer
metadata:
  labels: {name: mssql3, type: sqlservr}
  name: mssql3
  namespace: ag1
spec:
  acceptEula: true
  agentsContainerImage: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/ha:2019-CTP2.1
  availabilityGroups: [ag1]
  instanceRootVolumeClaimTemplate:
    accessModes: [ReadWriteOnce]
    resources:
      requests: {storage: 5Gi}
    storageClass: default
  saPassword:
    secretKeyRef: {key: sapassword, name: sql-secrets}
  sqlServerContainer: {image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CTP2.1'}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: {name: mssql3, namespace: ag1}
spec:
  ports:
  - {name: tds, port: 1433}
  selector: {name: mssql3, type: sqlservr}
  type: NodePort
  externalIPs:
    - x.x.x.30
    - x.x.x.31
    - x.x.x.32
    - x.x.x.33
    - x.x.x.34
    - x.x.x.35
---
EOF
```

Edit1:  kubectl logs -n ag mssql-operator-*

```
[sqlservers] 2020/08/14 14:36:48 Creating custom resource definition
[sqlservers] 2020/08/14 14:36:48 Created custom resource definition
[sqlservers] 2020/08/14 14:36:48 Waiting for custom resource definition to be available
[sqlservers] 2020/08/14 14:36:49 Watching for resources...
[sqlservers] 2020/08/14 14:37:08 Creating ConfigMap sql-operator
[sqlservers] 2020/08/14 14:37:08 Updating mssql1 in namespace ag1 ...
[sqlservers] 2020/08/14 14:37:08 Creating ConfigMap ag1
[sqlservers] ERROR: 2020/08/14 14:37:08 could not process update request: error creating ConfigMap ag1: v1.ConfigMap: ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta: readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, parsing 627 ...:{},"k:{\"... at {"kind":"ConfigMap","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"ag1","namespace":"ag1","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/ag1/configmaps/ag1","uid":"33af6232-4464-4290-bb14-b21e8f72e361","resourceVersion":"314186","creationTimestamp":"2020-08-14T14:37:08Z","ownerReferences":[{"apiVersion":"mssql.microsoft.com/v1","kind":"ReplicationController","name":"mssql1","uid":"e71a7246-2776-4d96-9735-844ee136a37d","controller":false}],"managedFields":[{"manager":"mssql-server-k8s-operator","operation":"Update","apiVersion":"v1","time":"2020-08-14T14:37:08Z","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:ownerReferences":{".":{},"k:{\"uid\":\"e71a7246-2776-4d96-9735-844ee136a37d\"}":{".":{},"f:apiVersion":{},"f:controller":{},"f:kind":{},"f:name":{},"f:uid":{}}}}}}]}}
[sqlservers] 2020/08/14 14:37:08 Updating ConfigMap sql-operator
[sqlservers] 2020/08/14 14:37:08 Updating mssql2 in namespace ag1 ...
[sqlservers] ERROR: 2020/08/14 14:37:08 could not process update request: error getting ConfigMap ag1: v1.ConfigMap: ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta: readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, parsing 627 ...:{},"k:{\"... at {"kind":"ConfigMap","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"ag1","namespace":"ag1","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/ag1/configmaps/ag1","uid":"33af6232-4464-4290-bb14-b21e8f72e361","resourceVersion":"314186","creationTimestamp":"2020-08-14T14:37:08Z","ownerReferences":[{"apiVersion":"mssql.microsoft.com/v1","kind":"ReplicationController","name":"mssql1","uid":"e71a7246-2776-4d96-9735-844ee136a37d","controller":false}],"managedFields":[{"manager":"mssql-server-k8s-operator","operation":"Update","apiVersion":"v1","time":"2020-08-14T14:37:08Z","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:ownerReferences":{".":{},"k:{\"uid\":\"e71a7246-2776-4d96-9735-844ee136a37d\"}":{".":{},"f:apiVersion":{},"f:controller":{},"f:kind":{},"f:name":{},"f:uid":{}}}}}}]}}
[sqlservers] 2020/08/14 14:37:08 Updating ConfigMap sql-operator
[sqlservers] 2020/08/14 14:37:08 Updating mssql3 in namespace ag1 ...
[sqlservers] ERROR: 2020/08/14 14:37:08 could not process update request: error getting ConfigMap ag1: v1.ConfigMap: ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta: readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, parsing 627 ...:{},"k:{\"... at {"kind":"ConfigMap","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"ag1","namespace":"ag1","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/ag1/configmaps/ag1","uid":"33af6232-4464-4290-bb14-b21e8f72e361","resourceVersion":"314186","creationTimestamp":"2020-08-14T14:37:08Z","ownerReferences":[{"apiVersion":"mssql.microsoft.com/v1","kind":"ReplicationController","name":"mssql1","uid":"e71a7246-2776-4d96-9735-844ee136a37d","controller":false}],"managedFields":[{"manager":"mssql-server-k8s-operator","operation":"Update","apiVersion":"v1","time":"2020-08-14T14:37:08Z","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:ownerReferences":{".":{},"k:{\"uid\":\"e71a7246-2776-4d96-9735-844ee136a37d\"}":{".":{},"f:apiVersion":{},"f:controller":{},"f:kind":{},"f:name":{},"f:uid":{}}}}}}]}}
```

I've looked over my operator and mssql2019.yamls (specifically around the kind: SqlServer, since that seems to be where it's failing) and can't identify any glaring inconsistencies or differences.

Comment: Added an update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

So your operator is running:

```sh
ag1           pod/pod/mssql-operator-68bcc684c4-rbzvn                   1/1     Running   0          86m   10.10.4.133   kw-02.bogus.local   <none>           <none>
```

I would start by looking at the logs there:

```sh
kubectl -n ag1 logs pod/mssql-operator-68bcc684c4-rbzvn
```

Most likely it needs to interact with the cloud provider (i.e Azure) and VMware is not supported but check what the logs say .

Update:

Based on the logs you posted it looks like you are using K8s 1.18 and the operator is incompatible. It's trying to create a ConfigMap with a spec that the kube-apiserver is rejecting.

✌️

Comment: Thanks Rico -- does this mean that the SQL install is specific to the K8s version?  If so, I suppose the answer is to either backport the K8s version (seems bad) or hit MS up for updated bits.

Comment: Yep, you've got it. Use an older K8s version or have MS fix the issue. I couldn't find the source code for the operator on github so I'm not sure where it is.

Answer (score 1):

> YAMLs mine are based off of: https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/high%20availability/Kubernetes/sample-manifest-files
>
> Run 3 scripts in this order: operator.yaml, sql.yaml, and ag-service.yaml.

I have just ran it on my GKE cluster and got similar result if I try running only these 3 files.

If you ran it without preparing PV and PVC ( `.././sample-deployment-script/templates/pv*.yaml` )

```
$ git clone https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples.git
$ cd sql-server-samples/samples/features/high\ availability/Kubernetes/sample-manifest-files/

$ kubectl create -f operator.yaml
namespace/ag1 created
serviceaccount/mssql-operator created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/mssql-operator-ag1 created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/mssql-operator-ag1 created
deployment.apps/mssql-operator created

$ kubectl create -f sqlserver.yaml 
sqlserver.mssql.microsoft.com/mssql1 created
service/mssql1 created
sqlserver.mssql.microsoft.com/mssql2 created
service/mssql2 created
sqlserver.mssql.microsoft.com/mssql3 created
service/mssql3 created

$ kubectl create -f ag-services.yaml 
service/ag1-primary created
service/ag1-secondary created
```

You'll have:

```
kubectl get pods -n ag1
NAME                              READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS   AGE
mssql-initialize-mssql1-js4zc     0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          6m12s
mssql-initialize-mssql2-72d8n     0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          6m8s
mssql-initialize-mssql3-h4mr9     0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          6m6s
mssql-operator-658558b57d-6xd95   1/1     Running                      0          6m33s
mssql1-0                          1/2     CrashLoopBackOff             5          6m12s
mssql2-0                          1/2     CrashLoopBackOff             5          6m9s
mssql3-0                          0/2     Pending                      0          6m6s
```

I see that the failed `mssql<N>` pods are parts of `statefulset.apps/mssql<N>`  and  `mssql-initialize-mssql<N>` are parts of `job.batch/mssql-initialize-mssql<N>`

Upon adding PV and PVC it looks in a following way:

```
 $ kubectl get all -n ag1 
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mssql-operator-658558b57d-pgx74       1/1     Running   0          20m
```

And 3 `sqlservers.mssql.microsoft.com` objects

```
$ kubectl get sqlservers.mssql.microsoft.com -n ag1 
NAME     AGE
mssql1   64m
mssql2   64m
mssql3   64m
```

That is why it looks exactly as it is specified in the abovementioned files.

> Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

However, if you run:

```
sql-server-samples/samples/features/high availability/Kubernetes/sample-deployment-script/$ ./deploy-ag.py deploy --dry-run
```

configs will be generated automatically.

without dry-run and that configs (and with properly set PV+PVC) it gives us 7 pods.

You'll have configs generated. It'll be useful to compare auto-generated configs with the one's you have (and compare running only subset 3 files vs. stuff from `deploy-ag.py` )

P.S.

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15+" GitVersion:"v1.15.11-dispatcher"
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15+" GitVersion:"v1.15.12-gke.2"
```

Comment: Thanks Nick -- what K8s version are you running if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: So I think I'm running into a K8s version difference like Rico offered.  Don't really want to back-port K8s to make this work.  MIght have to try something else.